# To add Images to a JavaScript Array and then display them on another function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I have a small problem here which I have been breaking my head over but somehow the solution has evaded me. Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

On a function `saveImages()` call, I have to save an image from a canvas to an `ImageArray` which is a Javascript array. I have declared the `ImageArray` as a global variable (i.e outside any of the functions)

```
var ImageArray = new Array(); // is this the proper way to do it?
```

Next, I call the saveImages() function.

```
function saveImages() {

  //here I draw on the canvas
   Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
   //window.open(Image, 'new_window');   // I see the window with the Jpeg Image data So I am sure that the image actually comes
   ImageArray[0].src = Image; // Looked up the internet to find that dataToURL can be used as img source
   no_of_pics_compared= ImageArray.length();
   alert('no_of_pics_compared' + no_of_pics_compared)     // I do not get this alert

}
```

I do not get the last alert which means that there is some flaw in the code which makes it stop working.

I want to be able to call this `saveImages()` function multiple times until a limit is reached (say 5) and want to display all the 5 images in the `ImageArray` on call of a separate function say `displayImages()`. This is the reason I want to keep the `ImageArray` as `global`

Can someone please tell me how do I correct what is going wrong. Thanks very  much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

var array = [] ;
array.push(Image) ;

Comment: The OP wants to push only the `src` not the image object.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't initialize the `ImageArray[0]` before setting its `src` property. You can write the following instead:

   ```
   ImageArray[0] = {
       src: Image
   };
   ```
2. Array's [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is a property, not a function, so it should be:

   ```
   no_of_pics_compared = ImageArray.length;
   ```
3. The question:

   ```
   var ImageArray = new Array(); // is this the proper way to do it?
   ```

   Yes! But you can write the following short version instead:

   ```
   var ImageArray = [];
   ```

   You can read more on how to create arrays in JavaSscript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

---

Finally, your code after the mentioned changes:

```
var ImageArray = [];

function saveImages() {
   Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
   ImageArray[0] = {
     src: Image
   };

   no_of_pics_compared= ImageArray.length;
   alert('no_of_pics_compared' + no_of_pics_compared);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an array first you have to create the object that you want to add to the array and then push it right to the array:

```
var ImageArray = new Array(); // Yes this is one of the proper ways to do it.
   //Second Way:
   // var ImageArray = [];
function saveImages() {

   var newImage = new Image();
   newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
   .
   .
   .
   ImageArray.push(newImage);  
   .
   .
   .

}
```

And also the length is a property not a function so you have to get it like this:

```
no_of_pics_compared= ImageArray.length;
```

Comment: Why he should add the whole image object if he only needs the `src` attribute's value???

Comment: When you create an Image object it loads the image in the background. It is a good practice if you want a seamless gallery loader. But as you said if he just wants the src he can just store them in an array.